# MOSS 2007: How do I move Project Pages from the C: drive to another drive

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have two drives on my server, C: & D:. I am out of storage on my C drive and need to validate that the multiple project pages I have created are being stored on C. The URL string does not point to any specific folder on the server.

How do I validate where project pages are stored, and if they are on my C Drive, can I move them to D without reinstalling the entire application?

Note, my SQL and Office applications are on D.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint stores all content as BLOBs inside of SQL. Only modified templates and actual application files are stored locally on drives.